# Convert rows to columns and group

Tags: sql, sql-server

The records in the first column can be of another type (1.1, 1.2), just take 2 to simplify the example.

```
SELECT com.NombrePuntoEntrega as Comedor, 
       a.NombreArea,  
       SUM(s.CantidadRaciones) as Cantidad
FROM PPA_SolicitudRaciones c inner join  
     PPA_SolicitudRacionesDET S on c.IdSolicitud =s.IdSolicitud and s.IdLocalidad =c.IdLocalidad 
     INNER JOIN PPA_AREAS A ON A.IDLOCALIDAD=S.IDLOCALIDAD  and a.IdArea =s.IdArea 
     INNER JOIN PPA_PuntosEntrega com on com.IdLocalidad =s.IdLocalidad and com.IdPuntoEntrega =s.IdPuntoEntrega 
WHERE (s.IdLocalidad =@IdLocalidad or @IdLocalidad =0)
     AND (s.IdArea =@IdArea or @IdArea =0)
     AND (c.FechaPedido between @FechaDel and @FechaAl   or   @FechaDel ='1900.01.01' )
     AND (c.IdTipoComida  =@TipoComida or @TipoComida=0)
GROUP BY com.NombrePuntoEntrega, a.NombreArea
```

Current output:

| Comedor | Nombre Area | Cantidad |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1 | APLICACIONES | 200 |
| 1.2 | APLICACIONES | 300 |
| 1.1 | ARANDANOS | 1000 |
| 1.1 | PALTO | 20 |
| 1.2 | PALTO | 30 |

Expected output:
groups the first row and then flips the other columns. Put a 0 where there are no records for the 'cantidad' column.

| Comedor | APLICACIONES | ARANDANOS | PALTO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1 | 200 | 1000 | 20 |
| 1.2 | 300 | 0 | 30 |

Comment: Have you tried to use PIVOT?

Comment: @RandyinMarin How do I handle it if I am grouping by 2 columns?

Comment: Perhaps use 2 PIVOTS?  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/192524/how-to-pivot-on-multiple-columns-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not a conditional aggregation

```
SELECT Comedor      = com.NombrePuntoEntrega 
      ,APLICACIONES = SUM(case when a.NombreArea = 'APLICACIONES' then s.CantidadRaciones else 0 end) 
      ,ARANDANOS    = SUM(case when a.NombreArea = 'ARANDANOS'    then s.CantidadRaciones else 0 end) 
      ,PALTO        = SUM(case when a.NombreArea = 'PALTO'        then s.CantidadRaciones else 0 end) 
  FROM PPA_SolicitudRaciones c inner join  
       PPA_SolicitudRacionesDET S on c.IdSolicitud =s.IdSolicitud and s.IdLocalidad =c.IdLocalidad 
 INNER JOIN PPA_AREAS A ON A.IDLOCALIDAD=S.IDLOCALIDAD  and a.IdArea =s.IdArea 
 INNER JOIN PPA_PuntosEntrega com on com.IdLocalidad =s.IdLocalidad and com.IdPuntoEntrega =s.IdPuntoEntrega 
 WHERE (s.IdLocalidad =@IdLocalidad or @IdLocalidad =0)
    AND (s.IdArea =@IdArea or @IdArea =0)
    AND (c.FechaPedido between @FechaDel and @FechaAl   or   @FechaDel ='1900.01.01' )
    AND (c.IdTipoComida  =@TipoComida or @TipoComida=0)
 GROUP BY com.NombrePuntoEntrega
```

Comment: What happens if the values of 'nombreArea' are dynamic and admite more values than APLICACIONES, ARANGANOS and PALTO?